# Docker commands not doing anything

Tags: docker

I have installed docker in MacOS. When I tpye "docker --version", it displays version. 
Other than this no command is working so far. It doesn't give any error also. 
After some time I have to press "Ctrl+C" to come out.

Comment: Could you share which errors encountered?

Comment: what is the output of the version? What commands did you run?

Comment: what do you want? which command do you try with docker? check docker service is running or not.

Comment: are the docker icon in your toolbar in the top right corner? 
On which way did you install docker? (direct/homebrew...)

Comment: @Mihai Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962

Comment: @MangduYogii even "docker" command itself is not displaying anything

Comment: @Wie yes, it is there. I installed docker directly.

Comment: Open Terminal, and enter this command to see that Docker is running OK:  docker run hello-world 
 >>it specifies the Docker image to run. If the image is not on your host system, it tries to pull it from the default Docker image registry.

Comment: @MangduYogii it is also not displaying anything

Comment: @Vika please add a screenshot, so we understand

Comment: can you try "docker system info"?

Comment: I restarted docker and it's running, don't know how? BTW thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Community Edition (CE) is a free download, so download Docker CE for Mac, then install and run the app. The whale should appear in your Mac’s status bar:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU0bV.png check out the screenshot